# Create column of unique randomly generated letters to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, sequence

I have a dataframe where there is one column of random letters and numbers, then a column of how many random letters/numbers need to be added to random string in the first column. Like so but my dataframe is 3+ million rows:

```
  id     missing
XK39J       4
NI94N       4
9IN3        5
MN83D       4
IUN2        5
```

I am using the following code to generate the new random sequence:

```
def id_generator(size, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(size))

data['new_id'] = data['missing'].apply(lambda x: id_generator(size = x))
data['final_id'] = data['id'] + data['new_id']
```

However, when I use this I end up getting a couple values in the 'final_id' column that are duplicates. But, I need each value in the 'final_id' column to be unique. Like:

```
id     missing     new_id      final_id
XK39J       4       NJI4       XK39JNJI4 
NI94N       4       BNER       NI94NBNER
9IN3        5       ER41J      9IN3ER41J
MN83D       4       9D4S       MN83D9D4S
IUN2        5       MNST3      IUN2MNST3
```

My idea was to store all the ids in a list and then get a new randomly  generated sequence if it matches but given that there will be 3million+ ids it won't work since iterating through a row of 3m will take too long. Like:

```
def id_generator(size, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    val_ls = []
    val = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(size))
    while val in val_ls:
       val = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(size))
    else:
       val_ls.append(val)
       return val
```

How can I ensure that there are no repeats?

Comment: If you want to add unique strings to each value, you need to loop, unfortunately…

Comment: Trying using a set instead of a list, that should speed up things

Comment: Also do you want to include all letters? would some letters and all numbers be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a brute-force but you could try something like this.

```py
from uuid import uuid4

# First generate final_id for all without caring about duplicates
df['new_id'] = df.missing.transform(lambda x: str(uuid4()).upper().replace('-', '')[:x])
df['final_id'] = df.id + df.new_id

# final_ids that are unique and already good
id_good = df.final_id.unique().tolist()

# Try re-generating final_id until we get no more duplicates
while(len(df[df.final_id.duplicated()]) > 0):
    dupe_mask = df.final_id.duplicated()

    # Regenerate final_id, store in temp column
    df.loc[dupe_mask, 'new_id'] = df.loc[dupe_mask].missing.transform(lambda x: str(uuid4()).upper().replace('-', '')[:x])
    df.loc[dupe_mask, 'temp'] = df.loc[dupe_mask].id + df.loc[dupe_mask].new_id

    # If the new final_id is not duplicates with currently good final_ids, keep it.
    df.loc[dupe_mask & ~df.temp.isin(id_good), 'final_id'] = df.loc[dupe_mask & ~df.temp.isin(id_good), 'temp']
    
    id_good += df.loc[dupe_mask & ~df.temp.isin(id_good), 'final_id'].unique().tolist()
    
    df = df.drop('temp', axis=1)
```

When I tested with 3M rows, it only had to do 1 loop, however, you might want to add timeout as this could theoretically ran forever.

Comment: Thank you, this solution didn't take too long and is better than checking every value in the list